# PC keeps restarting when booting

Tags: ubuntu, boot, nomodeset

Whenever I boot into my installed Ubuntu system, the entire system restarts.

I am able to get to the GRUB menu and select the Ubuntu OS, however while booting Ubuntu, my entire PC restarts.

The only message I get to see before the entire system restarts is this:

```
Base address is 0 assuming no 
IPMI interace.
```

Sometimes my entire screen also has red stripes and becomes distorted

You can view the image here:
[Image](https://pasteboard.co/sCn9SKDuwuHb.jpg)

The weird thing is, when I pass in the `nomodeset` paramater this issue does not occur, however my entire screen becomes stretched and weird. I try changing the screen resolution however I have no other option except 800x600

I do not believe the issue is with my graphics card since windows boots up fine and the screen resolution is also fine, however it also restarts a couple of times before booting up.

Currently, I reinstalled Ubuntu, erasing everything on my Hard disk hoping that would fix the issue, however the issue still arises.

PC Specifications:

HP Compaq 8200 Elite SFF

Intel core i5-2500k CPU

Intel HD 3000 graphics card

Comment: I was working on Ubuntu when everything froze. So I restarted my machine and it wouldn't boot. So I swapped the RAM and cleaned the inside of the computer hoping that would fix it. However it still persists.

Comment: I have also added a url to image of the boot screen. Now it has stopped restarting and shows a distorted screen